# How to make associations between 2 tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

Please help
I have two tables:

```
hospitals
id | name | adress | main_doctor_id

doctors
id | name | contacts | bio | hospital_id
```

In models:

```
hospital.rb
has_many :doctors

doctor.rb
belongs_to :hospital
```

But I need in one more association - each Hospital has one Chief doctor (main_doctor). How to create those association and how get data from Doctors for this main_doctor?
ruby 2.0.0p353
Rails 4.0.2

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get data from Doctors for this main_doctor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to build `main_doctor` association:

```
class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctors
  belongs_to :main_doctor, :class_name => 'Doctor'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. How I could get main_doctor data for each Hospital?  'h = Hospital.find(1); h.main_doctor or h.main_doctor.name' didn't work

Comment: @TheDobriy make sure this hospital has its `main_doctor`. What you showed in your comment is the proper way.

Comment: h.main_doctor.name
NameError: uninitialized constant Company::MainDoctor

Comment: h.main_doctor
NameError: uninitialized constant Company::MainDoctor

Comment: @TheDobriy of course, I'm sorry, my mistake. Check out edited answer.

Comment: `code`h = Hospital.find(2)
ArgumentError: Unknown key: class `code`... i don't anderstand how its workind

Comment: @TheDobriy I don't understand your comment. Could you be more clear?

Comment: @MarekLipka - do you know any magick way of connecting those associations? I.e. if I have a new record and I assign main_doctor I would like it to be added to doctors as well. I tried overriding setter, and it worked pretty well, however now I am having an issue with `doctors.first` and `main_doctor` returning two distinct objects.

Comment: @TheDobriy ok it was my mistake again. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse Nothing obvious comes into my mind at the moment. Maybe you could add callback, like `after_add`.

Comment: @BroiSatse I think there's no obvious reason for `doctors.first` to return the same object as `main_doctor`.

Comment: @MarekLipka - I'll make a question with an exact problem.

Comment: belongs_to :main_doctor, :class_name => 'Doctor' - now all works perfect! thanks a lot and sorry for my English :)

Comment: @MarekLipka - Seems I had some serious lag then. :)